# IE7 causing disappearance of background image on scroll

Tags: internet-explorer-7, background-image, css

I'm having an IE7 issue with a website i'm working on - [www.mini-meals.co.uk](http://www.mini-meals.co.uk)

Basically, the background image is not showing on behind the form on the 'Free Trial'
panel, and is disappearing when I scroll down on the others.

I've tried adding `position:relative;` on a bunch of elements but it doesn't seem to
make a difference.

Any ideas anyone? thanks.

Comment: Not that it fixes the problem, but you might want to remove one of the `<em>`'s right after *Home made chocolate brownie with cream*.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks.  Always better to have things neat and tidy :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this style to your page to see if you are experiencing an issue with hasLayout:

```
.panel .panel-wrapper { zoom: 1; }
```

If this does correct your issue than a more "standard" way of correcting the background rendering would be to set an explicit width to those same ".panel-wrapper" items.